# Subquery for comparison

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in my aggregation query:

```
name        release_year    iTunes                    Google                Microsoft
10 to Mid   2003            SDBUY,HDRENT,SDRENT       NULL                  NULL
100 Girls   2001            HDBUY                     HDBUY,HDRENT,SDRENT   SDBUY,SDRENT
100 Rifles  NULL            NULL                      HDBUY                 HDBUY,HDRENT
```

From this I would like to build the following result:

```
name         release_year    offers_on_itunes      top_platform    top_platform_offers
10 to Mid    2003            SDBUY,HDRENT,SDRENT   iTunes          SDBUY,HDRENT,SDREN
100 Girls    2001            HDBUY                 Google          SDBUY,SDRENT
100 Rifles   NULL            NULL                  Microsoft       HDBUY,HDRENT
```

In other words, we can get the first three columns in the result by doing:

```
SELECT name, release_year, itunes AS offers_on_itunes FROM (subquery)
```

But what would be the best way to get the top platform and the top platform offers? Perhaps doing `CASE` based on `LEN()` would get the `top_platform` but I'm not quite sure about the other. How would this best be constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `if` function, like below. I know it might get even messier comparing three columns, but hopefully this puts you on the right track...

```
SELECT name, release_year, itunes as offers_on_itunes,Google,
IF (itunes is null,0,
    ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(itunes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( itunes, ",", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH(",")  
    )  +1
) as numItunesOfferings,

IF (Google is null,0,
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(Google)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( Google, ",", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH(",")  
)  +1
) as numGoogleOfferings,
if (
    IF (itunes is null,0,
    ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(itunes)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( itunes, ",", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH(",")  
    )  +1
) > IF (Google is null,0,
ROUND (   
    (
        LENGTH(Google)
        - LENGTH( REPLACE ( Google, ",", "") ) 
    ) / LENGTH(",")  
    )  +1
),'itunes','Google') as top_platform
FROM (subquery)
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting this route, so basically I'd need to do a subquery here to get the one with the max count?

Comment: yeah though is the data in `subquery` for the offerings aggregated from relational tables? if so, perhaps an aggregate for the most offerings there would be simpler...

Comment: yes, how could we do that then? Maybe just add a few lines in your answer for how to do that?

Comment: so we kinda need to know how the relational tables are structured... is there an _offering_ table that has an offeringId, offeringName, etc, with values like 'SDBUY', 'HDRENT', 'SDRENT', a _platform_ table with platformId and platformName, with values like 'Google', 'Microsoft', 'iTunes' and then another relational table like platformOffering with platformId, offeringId and videoId (or whatever the UID of the videos is)?